# How to compare and get values from remote database

Tags: android

I am reading database values from MySQL on web in the form of ClickAble List.Show only one column value like "name".Now I want to read all values related to specific name like when Click on one name show all values related to that person.now I don't know how to get name from list and send to database and then read data only related to that particular name. Still don't try any code.....

Comment: Use webservices for your backend. Never make request directly your db from clientes.

Comment: will you please elaborate your point little bit more

Comment: Is a litle extensible topic, but here you can start https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WebServices/tutorial/Overview.html